# Dynamo AWS table doesn't let me uncheck DynamoDB JSON to see object in plain JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using golang to store data to dynamo.  I can save and retrieve the object in golang code no problem, however, when i go to the table items in aws console and click in any of the items stored it doesn't let me uncheck DynamoDB JSON checkbox to see the data in plain JSON not DynamoDB JSON.

Any ideas of what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Are you doing Scan or Query in the console? Do you have indexes?

Comment: It sounds like you're not having any issues in Go so this isn't a Go question, or really a programming question. You might try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: So by console i mean the AWS website table view,  and if that makes any difference I'm not doing any operation against the data just loading the first 10 items. I do have an index, but i don't think that's really relevant

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes AWS just can not convert the DynamoDB JSON to normal JSON due to some technical limitation.

Such as seen [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290926)

> When we insert a number with greater than 15 digits, DynamoDB enforces to use DynamoDB JSON to insert such numbers as DynamoDB JSON can handle numbers upto 38 digits precision.

Also this is not related to Coding question and should not be asked on SoF